# App crashes when storage().putFile is called with assets-library uri on iOS

Tags: react-native-ios, react-native-firebase

I am trying to upload an image from the camera roll of the phone to Firebase Storage using react-native-firebase. However, when I pass the uri of the image to the putFile method, the app crashes without an error.

For example:

```
const uri = 'assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=3DEE5FA3-9E58-479B-9AD9-A7FDBEDF0502&ext=JPG';
firebase.storage().ref('test.jpeg').putFile(uri)
                            .then(...)
                            .catch(...);
```

Is this the expected behavior? If yes, how can I transform the assets uri to a full file path?

Comment: I think might be same error, for me i follow https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1232 and it works (Check skbellevue comment)

Comment: Yes, I opened that issue when I didn't receive an answer here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug that was fixed in the RNFirebase release v4.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is getting this in the future, it may help to note that you can't upload to the root reference (e.g. `.ref()`).

Instead you need something like `.ref('images/xyz')`, etc.